# Where can I find "system proxy settings"?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, proxy

Where are these system proxy settings? I noticed my connection has been slow for a while, then I checked the connection settings and was surprised there were set a proxy, but I cant see what exactly it is using.

Where can I check which IP it was routing the connection for me ?

Here is what I saw from Firefox (12.0) options:

[image]

As far as I can remember, it has always been "no proxy" and not "system proxy". Unless new firefox version has set that "system proxy" to default?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proxy settings can be changed through:

- *Control Panel → Internet Options* (`inetcpl.cpl`) *→ Connections → LAN settings*

Comment: Is that really it? i mean, it opens the IE settings window... (i can change IE homepage etc through it too).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The "Connections" tab controls the behavior of all programs using WinINet/WinHTTP libraries, and so most third-party Windows programs have chosen to honor them as well.

Comment: What if access to those settings is locked down (as in my case). Any way to determine the proxy settings through the commandline (for example)?

Comment: `reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" | find /i "proxyserver"`

Comment: Note: 8 years later, Firefox still gets the proxy URL via WinInet, but it does not switch to auto-detect if `inetcpl.cpl` says autodetect. This is due to a [design decision](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=621429).